# hokuyo node bandwitdh

Tags: ros, wireless, wifi, hokuyo, bandwidth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I wish to have some comments from Hokuyo users.

I intend to have 5 bots, each with a laser, sharing data over an 802.11g link.
I think the laser should sample at 10Hz at least.

Since data processing would not be done on the robot itself, how much bandwidth are we talking here?

Will the wifi link be able to cope?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48910/hokuyo-node-bandwitdh/) by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 859 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-11-22**:
Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support). Always tag your questions appropriately.

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2012-11-26**:
Thank you for the headsup, I added some tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I remember correctly, the Hokuyo laser publishes between 700 and 800 range and intensity measurements of type float32 which corresponds to a little less than 6.5kb per scan. With a rate of 10Hz, that means that the overall data published by the laser will be less than 65kb/s which is not too much. I think, given your wifi link is stable and you do not have too many wifi devices and other networks around, you should not have too many problems.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) on 2012-11-26**:
Thank you, very exhaustive.